# how can I make a jquery tooltip based site guide?

Tags: jquery, css

It's something like when you signup on ymail.com , there is this thing, that tells you all about the site. It`s like that thing in microsoft office help.

So lets say I want a user to click on "I don`t understand anything" button, so a tooltip pops up and at first it is next to header, it tells in the tooltip: "Hey this is header, got it?" when user clicks yes, the tooltip moves to content and says "hey, this is sites content, got it?" and after it goes elsewhere etc etc etc.

Comment: Treat,
What are you asking for exactly?  Yes, this can be done with jQuery.  The methods you'll probably need to research are delegate() and click() followed by either append() and remove() or show() and hide()

Comment: Hi, I don`t know jQuery and I do not tend to learn it, I was asking more for already ready code to make some edits or a snippet I could edit.

Comment: There are some plugins that will provide some of the functionality you require. However they will all require some level of jQuery knowledge. E.G. http://plugins.jquery.com/project/qtip

Comment: Also if you "do not tend[sic] to learn" jQuery then asking a question about how to implement some functionality using it is not overly helpful.

Comment: hi @jacob.toye, i was looking ar qtip earlier, but i have no idea how to make it be there not only when i hover something but all the time, also i would like to know how can i make a button to close the first tooltip and then show the next one and so on.

Comment: To satisfy my own interest, how do you find yourself in the position of having to implement something like this _without_ knowing at least a little jQuery? Are you a dev with other skills? or have you had this task forced upon you? Please accept this question in the spirit it is intended; I have no idea about your situation nor do I want to cause offence. I'm just interested.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean now. qTip probably isn't the appropriate solution for you. What you are after would require you to create a small widget using html/javascript/css. I'm not aware of any out of the box plugin to achieve this. Although I was amused when I searched 'jQuery Clippy' in google and found this: http://www.yankov.us/clippy/ (plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/clippy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you might be looking for is something like [Amberjack2](http://amberjack2.org/), or jQuery version of it [here](https://github.com/salesking/king_tour) (only minimally jQuerified).